# adding uibuttons programmatically

Tags: iphone, uibutton

here i have this code that i'm trying where 
`openingHoursView.ohLocation` has two values "**value1**" and "**value2**".
So does `openingHoursView.idNum` with values "**id1**" and "**id2**".
When i execute my code I only get one button with the name of "**value2**" and "**id2**". So my question would be how to create all the buttons for the values of `openingHoursView.ohLocation` and     `openingHoursView.idNum`

```
- (void)loadView {

    storeAppDelegate = (StoreAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    

    int row = [storeAppDelegate.openingHoursLocationsDelegate count]-1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= row; i++) {
        openingHoursView = [storeAppDelegate.openingHoursLocationsDelegate objectAtIndex:i];

        self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        //create the button
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        //set the position of the button
        if (i%2 != 0) {
            button.frame = CGRectMake(30 , 100 , 150, 30);

        }else {
            button.frame = CGRectMake(30 , 100 + i*50, 150, 30);
        }


        //set the button's title
        [button setTitle:openingHoursView.ohLocation forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        //listen for clicks
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = [openingHoursView.idNum intValue];
        //add the button to the view
        [self.view addSubview:button];
    }
}

-(IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender {
    UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;

    NSLog(@"User clicked %d", button.tag);
    // Do something here with the variable 'sender'
}
```

Just an explanation objectAtIndex:0 for openingHoursView.ohLocation is "**value1**" and for  objectAtIndex:1 is "**value2**". Same procedure for openingHoursView.idNum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

inside the `for` loop and thus gets overwritten on each iteration. You should only do it once before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new view for every button in

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```

Put this code before the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

`UIButton` *`button` = [[`UIButton` `alloc`]`init`];
[`self`.`view` addsubView:button];